# How should I do an Enum comparison in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums, jhipster

I have a jhipster project and they just chanced the enum from this:

```
export enum DeclarationStatus {
  NEW = 'NEW',
  DRAFT = 'DRAFT',
  APPROVED_BY_FREELANCER = 'APPROVED_BY_FREELANCER',
  APPROVED_BY_CLIENT = 'APPROVED_BY_CLIENT',
  APPROVED = 'APPROVED'
}
```

to this:

```
export enum DeclarationStatus {
  NEW,
  DRAFT,
  APPROVED_BY_FREELANCER,
  APPROVED_BY_CLIENT,
  APPROVED
}
```

First I could do a comparison like this:

```
status === DeclarationStatus.APPROVED_BY_FREELANCER;
```

But now that does not work any more because the enum is actually a number. This does work how ever:

```
DeclarationStatus[''+status] === DeclarationStatus.APPROVED_BY_FREELANCER;
```

So my question is which is better. Or is there even a 3rd option?

---

I set this question to answered. The Jhipster community reverted the change to initialized. So then comparison is easy again.

Thanks to @vicpermir who made it happen.

Comment: Not one is better than the other. One has number values, the other has string values. With the second one `status` should be a number, otherwise use the first one.

Comment: status is filled from backend and in Java it is a real enum, with json it is converted into a string. So indeed I like the first one better. But than why did the jhipster team change it to the second....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the string enum is not initialized. As long as your enums are not defined as `const` you can make a very similar comparison as your old method.

```js
status === DeclarationStatus[DeclarationStatus.APPROVED_BY_FREELANCER];
```

In other words, the following should work:

```js
enum Initialized {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B'
}

enum NotInitialized { // equivalent to
    A,                // A = 0,
    B                 // B = 1
}

status = 'A';

// String enum initialized
let test1 = (status === Initialized.A); // true

// String enum not initialized
let test2 = (status === NotInitialized.A); // false
let test3 = (status === NotInitialized[NotInitialized.A]); // true :)
```

In the official github repo for the [JHipster Generator](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster) there is a recently merged pull request ([PR#11218](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/11218)) that fixes this problem for React and forces the generator to always initialize string enums.

Remember that, as described in the [JDL docs](https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/enums), you can also force this initialization:

```java
enum DeclarationStatus {
   NEW (NEW),
   DRAFT (DRAFT)
}
```

More info about TypeScript Enums can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html).

Comment: Interesting! 

"In the official github repo for the JHipster Generator there is a recently merged pull request (PR#11218) that fixes this problem for React and forces the generator to always initialize string enums.".

Because for Angular they moved from initialized to  not initialized. That was why I started this discussion.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Both angular and react should initialize string enums. It looks like this problem was introduced alongside custom enum values [here](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/10911/commits/2c1c9b67193cf987008c1d1a8f928abafbda1603).

Comment: I have `enum Initialized { A = 'A' }` but still this returns false: `myResponse.type.toLowerCase() === Initialized.A.toLowerCase()`!